# Convert keyboard shortcut label to Input.dispatchKeyEvent (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-debugging

I want to use the Input.dispatchKeyEvent API defined at https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/

An example invocation of this API is:

```
const eventArgs = {
  'modifiers': 0,
  'text': 'e',
  'unmodifiedText': 'e',
  'key': 'e',
  'code': 'KeyE',
  'windowsVirtualKeyCode': 69,
  'type': 'keyDown'
};
Input.dispatchKeyEvent(eventArgs);
```

I want to dynamically generate these eventArgs from a keyboard shortcut label such as:

`Ctrl + Alt + e`

Has anyone come across a similar conversion function?

- The modifiers could be easily parsed to create the bitmap I suppose.
- I'm not too sure on the differences between text, unmodifiedText, key, and code.
- The windowsVirtualKeyCode I think can be derived from 'e'.charCodeAt(0).

I might be able to come up with some trial-and-error tables, but if someone's seen/done this before that could help a lot!